# Is saved_model.pb from keras.models.save_model the same with tensorflow freeze_graph output .pb file?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, save, protocol-buffers

After a model is trained in keras, I used to apply `tf.compat.v1.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants` or `freeze_graph.py` to freeze model and output **.pb** file. Like this:

```
output_graph_def = tf.compat.v1.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess, input_graph_def, output_node_names)
with tf.gfile.GFile('model.pb', "wb") as f:  
    f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

Recently, I find `tf.compat.v1.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants` is labeled with: `Warning: THIS FUNCTION IS DEPRECATED`.

So I'm looking for a updated method of generate `.pb` file. I find this: `keras.models.save_model()` to save model and output dir contains:

> assets  saved_model.pb  variables

I'm not sure if this `saved_model.pb` is the same with output `.pb` file of `tf.compat.v1.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants`?

If not, could someone recommed a better way to get frozen model (.pb) file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have confirmed they are not the same .pb file. If you load and run SavedModel format, you'll get error: `Data loss: Can't parse testmodel/saved_model.pb as binary proto`